# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException - Jersey Client

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am attempting to read a REST web service response in a client and it works fine for individual calls. While doing the load test (~5000 calls in 5 minutes) for same web service call, I am getting socket read time out error.

The bigger problem is, the socket time error actually happens after a  web service response is successfully received (checked via wireshark) (may be jersey client is confused).

Earlier I was using Jersey client 1.x, now tried the same with Jersey client 2.x and still we see the error.

I have checked most of the read timeout examples in stack overflow and couldn't find an appropriate case

[java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out under tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079273/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-under-tomcat)
[fix java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043573/fix-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out)

[java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out under tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079273/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-under-tomcat)

I am getting the following error

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read
>   timed out     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287

Just wanted to confirm on few things. Any suggestions will really help me to get directions on debugging the issue.

1. Is there a possibility in Jersey client to get confused when the
   volume of API calls are 5000 in a span of 5 minutes. I see socket
   timeout only that time
2. I believe if the content-length is mismatched then jersey may wait for the Rest service to send more output. Not sure if that will be
   the case
3. The API response time is not a very large one, typically time 7 ~ 10 seconds.

Note : I am not a Java Developer and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. no.
You can debug this issue further by setting the read timeout for jersey http client like so:
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 100); // in milliseconds